# Use of undeclared identifier 'createWithNode'

Tags: objective-c, undeclared-identifier

Please excuse my ignorance, I am a newbie iOS coder :)

I downloaded a project with examples from Sudzc - it creates code that supports the connection of iOS to SOAP-based web services. I integrated the code into my project and when I run the project I get a compile error in one of the classes created to handle arrays of long values in the web service. Can anyone tell me what the issue is? I am stumped.

The error I get is

```
IIDArrayOflong.m:20:26: Use of undeclared identifier 'createWithNode'
```

Here is the Class code. I marked the line throwing the error....

```
@implementation IIDArrayOflong

+ (id) createWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
    if(self = [self init]) {
        for(CXMLElement* child in [node children])
        {
            //**ERROR THROWN ON THE NEXT LINE
            long long value = [[ createWithNode: child] object]; 
            [self addObject: value];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+ (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSArray*) array
{
    NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString string];
    for(id item in array) {
        [s appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lld", item]];
    }
    return s;
}
@end
```

Also, confused as to why the variable declaration is

```
long long value = ...
```

What does this mean?

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided an object for the selector to be called on. Since `createWithNote:` is a class method, you should call it on your `class`.

```
long long value = [[[self class] createWithNode: child] object];
```

The `long long value =` is equivalent to `int64_t value =`. It's declaring a variable named `value` that is a 64-bit integer.

Comment: The helpful bit to point out is that the `+` before the method declaration denotes it as a class method, as opposed to a `-` before instance methods. Within each pair of braces `[]` there should be a recipient, and a method, so for class methods `[SomeClass methodName:parameter]` and for instance methods `[anInstance methodName:parameter]` look right. `[ createWithNode: child]` is missing a recipient left of the method name.

Comment: Hi, @Ian MacDonald, I have the same issue - I understand your explanation, 10x for it, but after setting the correction I have an issue "Implicit conversion of 'long long' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC" on the next row and warning about the same on the same row. I understand that SUDZC try to set long value to a pointer and via versa, but I can not understand how to fix it. Can you advise me?

Comment: @new2ios: the `-[IIDArrayOfLong object]` selector that this question is using is defined to return a `long long` value. You need to capture the return value of this method with the appropriate variable type for your usage.

Comment: 10x for the quick replay @Ian MacDonald. I understand. I replaced those 2 lines with `[self addObject: [[[self class] createWithNode: child] object]];`. I have to check if this is correct solution when I reach that stage, but for now I can compile my project. 10x again